# React Element Tag not accepting both Function and React.Component types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Component signatures:

```
export default class Page1 extends React.Component<{}, SomeInterface>
export default function Page2() : JSX.Element
```

In main runner:

```
render() {
    const Pages= [Page1, Page2]
    const Current = Pages[<either page>]
    return <>
        <Current />
    </>
```

I'm getting a 'Type {} is not assignable to type 'never'. Since both Page1 and Page2 go through React.createElement and are both compatible with it, why aren't they able to be mixed in an array?  I can make Pages only classes or only function components but never a mix of both.

Comment: Look at that error again, then look at `export default class Page1 extends React.Component<{}, SomeInterface>`.

Comment: This seems to work for me.  What's different about yours?  https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-matsumoto-fgqxi